# CXF incorrect WSDL automatically generated?

Tags: header, wsdl, cxf

I am fighting the last two days with the same problem and I don't know how to fix this. Even not sure if it is an error or not.

I have a CXF Web Service with something I consider very strange and I would like to fix. This is one of the calls that the Web Service deals with:

```
@WebResult (name="merchantHierarchyParentResponse") MerchantHierarchyParentResponseDTO
getParent(
        @WebParam(name="institutionNumber") @XmlElement(required=true) String institutionNumber,
        @WebParam(name="clientNumber") String clientNumber,
        @WebParam(name="ourReference") String ourReference,
        @WebParam(name="accessMerch") String accessMerch,
        @WebParam(header=true, name="callerId") String callerId,
        @WebParam(header=true, name="timestamp") String timestamp,
        @WebParam(header=true, name="signature") String signature
);
```

As you can see, it receives 4 normal parameters plus 3 extra parameters in the header (callerId, timestamp and signature).

It compiles successfully. Then I deploy it also successfully in a WebLogic server.

Finally, I use SoapUI to test it. I provide SoapUI with the URL that WebLogic is providing me with the WSDL. This is, I am not doing any change in the automatic generated WSDL. This is what I am getting for this getParent in SoupUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webService.webservice.omnipay.com.server/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <web:signature>?</web:signature>
      <web:timestamp>?</web:timestamp>
      <web:callerId>?</web:callerId>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:getParent>
         <institutionNumber>?</institutionNumber>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <clientNumber>?</clientNumber>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ourReference>?</ourReference>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <accessMerch>?</accessMerch>
      </web:getParent>
      <web:callerId>?</web:callerId>
      <web:timestamp>?</web:timestamp>
      <web:signature>?</web:signature>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My question is very clear. I see the 3 parameters in the header section (callerId, timestamp and signature) but why these 3 parameters are AGAIN at the end in the body part. I don't want them in the body part, I want them only in the header.

Any idea why this is happening? Is it a bug?

Comment: Please copy your comment to an answer for this question and approve it if that fixed the issue. As such, the question will not show up ad unanswered in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks to the people that helped me to fix the problem.

Here the portion of the wsdl:binding related with the getParent call:

```
<wsdl:binding name="ServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getParent">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input name="getParent">
            <soap:header encodingStyle="" message="tns:getParent" part="callerId" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header encodingStyle="" message="tns:getParent" part="timestamp" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header encodingStyle="" message="tns:getParent" part="signature" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getParentResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I had to change in the section , this line

```
<soap:body use="literal"/>
```

for this one

```
<soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
```

Not very sure why this parts attribute was not generated in my automatically generated WSDL, but well, it fixed my problem. I don´t like to make this manual change in the wsdl. Anyway, at least my problem is fixed.